# Why does Entropy function not working in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

For finding entropy of the image I used this matlab code first

```
PIC = imread('c.bmp');

I = imhist(PIC);

C = I./sum(I);


bar(I)

E = entropy(C)
```

It gave me the wrong result then I used

```
E = -sum(C.*log2(C))
```

And it gave me the correct result 
Can anyone please explain what wrong did I do in the first case?  I am new in image processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two commonly-used forms of entropy: binary entropy, and natural entropy (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Definition)). They only differ in the bases: one is to base 2, and one is to base *e*. The transformation you did is exactly what is needed to transfer one to the other.

Comment: Ohkay. Now I understand didn't know about the base e one. Thanks a lot!